# Some doubts about the -u param of the diff command in GIT

Tags: git, bash, diff, git-bash

I am pretty new in **GIT** and I have the following doubt.

I am comparting 2 txt file that contains different text with this command:

```
$ diff -u file.txt updated.txt
--- file.txt    2016-07-22 10:38:35.898833500 +0200
+++ updated.txt 2016-07-22 10:39:36.322025800 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-blablabla
\ No newline at end of file
+blablabla ciao
```

I think that it only means that the first file contains **blablabla** and the scond file contains also the **ciao** word after **blablabla** . Is it the correct interpretation of the output?

What exactly means the **-u** param of the diff command?

Then I have performed **diff** without the **-u** parameter:

```
$ diff file.txt updated.txt
1c1,9
< blablabla
\ No newline at end of file
---
> blablabla ciao
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
```

This output seems more clear to me because with the **<** menans that the line of the **file.txt** contains less information the the **updated.txt** and the **>** means that the **updated.txt** contains more information then the **file.txt**.

Is it correct?

What exactly does the **-u** param and when is convenient to use it?

Comment: Just a note - you're probably being downvoted because your question is mislabelled as git question, when in fact it is not.

Comment: Also, you don't indicate that you've read `git diff --help`, or else the question would be "why would I want to use the unified diff format?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-u` says to use the *unified diff* format, a more compact *context diff*. It includes three lines of context to make the diff more likely to apply when other changes are present, i.e. if your source file is not the original but for example has inserted lines before the hunk to patch.

For short files and edits at the beginning and end of file there obviously can't be lines of context.